# Is there a way to detect SQL Dialect without knowing the database type?

Tags: sql, odbc, dbeaver

I'm using Dbeaver to connect via ODBC to a database. I have no idea what type of database it is. It might be proprietary. Who knows?

Is there a way to figure out what dialect of SQL to use? LIMIT statements aren't working, and I don't want to destroy things by selecting * all day long.

I've tried a couple other ways to limit results - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(SQL)#Limiting_result_rows - but I couldn't find an option that worked.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can we assume that you are connecting via an ODBC DSN so you don't even see what the `DRIVER=` name is? If so, can you look at the DSN definition to get more information about the backend to which you are connecting?

Comment: Figured it out! But yes you can assume that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are doing this database server identification one time, you can issue queries to see which ones work or fail to determine the database server type.

For SQL Server, there are many such as selecting one of the @@ variables Select `@@version`.

For Oracle, `Select 1 FROM DUAL;`

Both queries do not modify any data and should run quickly.  There are equivalent others for other database servers.

One could also look at the connection string and find out what type of database driver is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Tried a few more limit-style statements and found it to be SQL Server/ Access

Comment: The SQL inside Access is not fully SQL Server compliant.